# Stop script from being executed more than 5 seconds

Tags: php, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop A Script (without fatal error) After A Certain Amount of Query/Parse Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502758/stop-a-script-without-fatal-error-after-a-certain-amount-of-query-parse-time)

Is it possible to stop a script if it's been running for more than 5 seconds in PHP?

I have no idea how I'd be able to tell how long it's been running for.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to limit execution time:

```
// At the beginning of your script
set_time_limit(5);
```

Also read the warning box on the documentation site:

> This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is
>   no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time
>   limit in the php.ini.